# Weblogic MDB Cluster Load Balancing

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, load-balancing, message-driven-bean

We have two JVMs in a weblogic cluster configured to consume messages from a websphere queue manager. When ever more number of message comes in, we see most of the time one JVM is busy in processing message and the other one is being idle. is there any configuration available in weblogic that helps to MDBs on both JVM equally share or load balance the messages within a cluster?

Here are Configuration Details:

We have total six servers and three clusters with two servers each.

1. Cluster Messaging Mode: Multicast
2. Migration Basis: Database Default
3. Load Algorithm: Round Robin Affinity.

Note: Let me know if any specify property is needs to be specified.

We have three IBM MQ Servers and six weblogic foreign JMS Listeners (targeted to each one of the server) and each two foreign JMS listener are configured to consume messages from one MQ server.

We tried targeting the Foreign Listener to cluster but weblogic did not take it and we are not sure if we have missed something on the configuration.

Let me know if you need more information.

I was trying to post some image but it did not allow and saying it requires minimum 10 reputation.

Comment: You need to add more details about your weblogic setup. There are MANY clustering and load balancing options in weblogic

Comment: Updated with more details.